# How to handle separators with dynamic flex wrapping?

Tags: css

I have a flex container with 2 children separated by a separator div. The container is free to wrap children on small widths. How to handle the separator in this case? I am able to stretch the separator along the row when it wraps, but what to do when children wrap partially?

Demo: https://codepen.io/chinchang/pen/QWQyVBe

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left, .right {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 99999999;
  min-width: 200px;
}
.separator {
  background: red;
  padding: 2px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">left side</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right">right side</div>
  
</div>
```

Issue video -> https://twitter.com/i/status/1523197608939847682

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea using `clamp()` (related article to understand the logic: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-layouts-fewer-media-queries/)

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left, .right {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.separator {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: clamp(0px,(400px - 100%)*999,100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">left side</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right">right side</div>
  
</div>
```